# asp:repeater generate clientid with "-" special char for javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, repeater, requiredfieldvalidator

I've a asp.repeater control in my asp.net page

[image]

At debug time I can see it automatically generate a clientid with "-" char where I've no control over it but it ok for me at this point...

[image]

...then on ItemDataBound I use a RequiredFieldValidator controls that inherit that clientID after I add it in repeater

[image]

Now the problem is that RequiredFieldValidator automatically add some client Javavascript var using that ClientId, and special char "-" is not allowed in javascript firing up a Syntax Error

[image]

This is the Javascript auto generated by RequiredFieldValidator  control

[image]

How I can solve this?
from what I know it is no possible set ClientID by code and then how to fix it?

Below I add the screen-shot of the error indicators in the Chrome script debugger

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that's the line generating the syntax error in JavaScript?  Hyphens are very much allowed in strings in JavaScript.  Can you follow the console error in Chrome to view the line of code it references and capture the error indicators in the Chrome script debugger?

Comment: Thank You David, I'm sure, I've also added the screen-shot of the error indicators in the Chrome script debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved.
On Asp.Net 4.0 there is more control over ClientID, for my problem I've fixed with the ID of parent control. Indeed the ClientID for child controls is automatically builded statring from ID of parent control.
For similar problem I've also find other solution working aroun ClientIDMode.
You have full control over ClienID setting parent control to ClientMode to static and child controls with ClientMode to Predictable.
Useful post I found around this can be read here: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2009/nov/07/clientidmode-in-aspnet-40